# Angular-Interceptor: How to manage multiple loader/spinner on the page

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

We have an Angular6 application, where we have different components on the page, and each components has `<loader isLoading={loading} />` to display the loader when making API call. But this process is manual, each component has to maintain loading flag for this purpose.

I want the ***interceptor*** to handle this. I have written the code, but it is working partially correct.

**App Behavior**

[image]

With my implementation, it keeps showing the loader unless until each API call finishes. (Keeping the count of API calls)

So how do I ***only show those loader for which API call is not yet completed and hide those for which API is completed***.

**Interceptor Implementation**

```
export class HttpCommonInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.loader.start();
        this.loaderCount++;
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    this.loaderCount--;
                    if (this.loaderCount === 0) {
                        this.loader.stop();
                    }
                    return of(event);
                }
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                this.loader.stop();
                this.loaderCount--;
                console.log('Error caught in interceptor ', error);
                return of(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The operation inside your interceptor is asynchronous so when you call eg. `this.loader.stop()` and some template reads it's value doesn't trigger change detection so try wrapping `this.loader.stop()` inside `NgZone.run(() => {...})`

Comment: @martin what I mean to say, If component1 api completes, then it should hide the loader for component1, but should display other components loader as other apis are still not completed.

Comment: I do you think you should associate this with Httpinterceptor. Beacuse Loading is a UI task and not neccessary to be http call.

Comment: @FanCheung This is how it is currently implemented UI is managing the loader and it is only for HTTP calls. But it is cluttered everywhere. So I was thinking of abstracting that functionality out of UI, so it should be at the one place.

Comment: that will normally give you more trouble in the long run. Loader is a very generic component. You can instead create a reusable component with loader in it.